# Finished Threads: should i ignore them?

Tags: java, multithreading, visualvm

I wrote a web crawler that opens many web pages. As you can see in the image below, some threads seem to be finished (white color), but what does it mean? Do I have some bug? Is there a leak of resources? And, how can I have an idea about where those threads are generated and why are they finished? Should I worry about them?

[VisualVM](http://snag.gy/hnKOI.jpg)

The problem is that if i keep it running for a day, i get thousands of that threads, so i'm worried about it.

Comment: If you are building up more and more threads over the course of a day and they never tear down, then yes you have a leak.  I would write a unit test that asserts that the code tears down its resources after it has completed its task.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to start lots of threads, as long as not too many of them are alive at the same time. "Finished" threads are no longer alive, so they won't cause issues.

Having said that, in Java threads are rather expensive to create (this can be different in other languages, like Erlang), and you usually don't want / don't need to create lots of threads during the course of your app's life. You may want to use a Thread Pool. This will re-use threads instead of starting a new one many times.

Answer (score 1):

The finished threads will not kill your application. But instead of creating new threads that we'll be finished, use a thread pool that will re-use them.